# PHP mail() function is not sending data to my email

Tags: php, email, smtp

```
          <?php

            $to = "faizy.wali@gmail.com";
            $subject = "Mail Test at". strftime("%T", time());
            $message = "This is a test";
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
            $from  = "faizy.haiyyul@gmail.com";
            $headers = "From: {$from}";
            $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
           echo $result? 'Sent' : 'Error';
           ?>
```

> My php version is 5.3 and i am not using any SMTP library,I am using simple mail function in php,The script is working good but this script is not sending email to my mail account,The output of my script is SENT but not even a single mail is received in my mail account

Comment: i have just tried to send simple mail

Comment: @Faizy - and what happens when you try? Do you get the Sent or Error message? Do you have an SMTP server configured?

Comment: It gives sent,No SMTP server is not configured

Comment: Or you can use php mailer library. very easy to use